# Find intersections between rows and timestamps in a mysql db

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, postgresql, timestamp

I have a table, where events of certain objects are listed.

There are two events: "movement" and "load". They can start and end, and these events are listed with timestamps when they happened.

Now i want to calculate the following three numbers:

- sum of time, when movement took place (value in the fiddle: 700)
- sum of time, when load took place (value in the fiddle: 630)
- sum of time, when movement and load took place (value in the fiddle: 611)

I have created a sqlfiddle for the problem here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be512

Comment: +1 for setting up a schema to play with, though I am sure people will ask to see your go first `;-)`

Comment: Maybe there's a possibility to join the table with it self and then calculate this numbers...but i couldn't get it done.

Comment: If you can paste in what you tried, people will advise you how to modify it.

Comment: Is is possible to have the following order of events for a single MAC : `movement_start, load_start, movement_end, load_end` and/or `movement_start, load_start, load_end, movement_end` and/or `movement1_start, movement2_start, movement2_end, movement1_end`? ... Independent from your answer: I think it might be better to use another row format: `id, mac, event, start_time, stop_time`. **1.:** takes less space in the database. **2.:** it's much more easy to calculate the sum of time.

Comment: Regarding the format, it's no problem to switch to `id, mac, event, start_time, stop_time`, i will prepare a fiddle to try that.

Comment: Can you explain how you have determined if the movement events are "Load" or "No Load" in your fiddle. I am about [half way there](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9146/49), but can't quite figure out the logic for the first bit. Also the difference between rows 18 and 19 appears to be 20, is this an error or am I missing something?

Comment: And please provide an answer, concerning the order of events. That's pretty important for calculation. (but it's no more important with the new row scheme)

Comment: @CL: What do you mean? Can you tell which numbers explicit?

Comment: @GarethD : You're right, i have corrected the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3d474

Comment: @BenjaminM "no load" means that in between the start/end timestamps of "movement" there is no load event, which currently takes place.

Comment: But is it possible to have nested movements (and/or nested loads and/or both nested) as in the example provided?

Comment: Also, do you want only the effective time? I mean, in your fiddle you are counting time AFTER the end event but BEFORE the next start event as part of the total. For example in row 17 you are counting 10 seconds towards the total time, even though this is the time from the end of one load event to the start of the next load event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two columns compute the differences between corresponding `end`/`start` events.
(Summation is commutative, so we don't need to actually match corresponding events.)

The third colum searches for `movement start` events for which the preceding `load` event is a `load start` event, and for `movement end` events for which the following `load` event is a `load end` event.

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(timestamp)
        FROM Table1
        WHERE event = 'movement end') -
       (SELECT SUM(timestamp)
        FROM Table1
        WHERE event = 'movement start') AS all_movement,

       (SELECT SUM(timestamp)
        FROM Table1
        WHERE event = 'load end') -
       (SELECT SUM(timestamp)
        FROM Table1
        WHERE event = 'load start') AS all_load,

       (SELECT SUM(timestamp)
        FROM Table1 a
        WHERE event = 'movement end' AND
              (SELECT event
               FROM Table1 b
               WHERE timestamp = (SELECT min(timestamp)
                                  FROM Table1 c
                                  WHERE c.timestamp >= a.timestamp
                                    AND c.event LIKE 'load %')
              ) = 'load end') -
       (SELECT SUM(timestamp)
        FROM Table1 a
        WHERE event = 'movement start' AND
              (SELECT event
               FROM Table1 b
               WHERE timestamp = (SELECT max(timestamp)
                                  FROM Table1 c
                                  WHERE c.timestamp <= a.timestamp
                                    AND c.event LIKE 'load %')
              ) = 'load start') AS load_movement;
```

Comment: I look for the three values i have mentionend in the beginning: 700,690,611

Comment: Read GarethL's comment. My query does *not* count the time between an `end` and the following `start` event.

Comment: One last question: Is it possible to calculate this values distinct all ID's and days?

Comment: That's a new question. And then you should specify what kind of timestamp this is.

Comment: Ok ;), have done it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114811/find-intersections-between-rows-and-timestamps-in-a-mysql-db-group-by-days-and

Answer (score 2):

Try this

For load answer will be 630 not 690

For the 1st and second case

```
SELect max(timestamp) - min(timestamp), LEFT(event, LOCATE(' ', event)) 
FROM table1 
group by id, LEFT(event, LOCATE(' ', event));
```

For 3 rd case

```
SELect max(timestamp) - min(timestamp), id
FROM table1 
group by id;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9146/67)

Comment: 630 and 700 are correct, but 710 is not the correct number...it should 611?

Comment: Your start value is `1351508000` and end one is `1351508710` it returns 710 :P

Comment: It is not 690 it is 630 for load correct that thing in question.

Answer (score 1):

this is the query to get the time between start and end:

```
select sum(a.timestamp-b.timestamp) from Table1 a join Table1 b on a.rowid-b.rowid=1 and a.rowid%2=0 and a.event='movement end';
```

similary, between end and start:

```
select sum(a.timestamp-b.timestamp) from Table1 a join Table1 b on a.rowid-b.rowid=1 and a.rowid%2=1 and a.event='movement start';
```