# Find overlaps between timestamps in different rows in a mysql db, group by days and ID's

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, timestamp

I have a table, where events of certain objects are listed.

There are two events: "movement" and "load". They can start and end, and these events are listed with timestamps when they happened.

With the following request, i can get the following values:

```
sum of time, when movement took place (value in the fiddle: 421)
sum of time, when load took place (value in the fiddle: 520)
sum of time, when movement and load took place (value in the fiddle: 391)
```

The current version calculates these numbers for each DAY, this works fine.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/518dd/1

But i will also have different ID's. I want now to calculate these numbers for each DAY and for each ID. When I add this data, it crashes, see this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b43fa/6

This is not a duplicate to this question: [Find intersections between rows and timestamps in a mysql db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112004/find-intersections-between-rows-and-timestamps-in-a-mysql-db), because the solution to this question is not suitable/adaptable in this case.

Comment: You have already asked this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112004/find-intersections-between-rows-and-timestamps-in-a-mysql-db/15112934#15112934

Comment: why have you created another question?

Comment: @BenjaminM . . . Clearly, he asked another question, because the accepted answer on the first question does not easily generalize to grouping by `id` and date.  Instead of invalidating that question, he chose (reasonably in my opinion) to ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown by Gordon, grouping is made possible by moving the filtering into the outermost `SELECT`.
The search for the loading events that need to enclose the movement events is done in the same way as in the [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112004#15112972):

```
SELECT id,
       date(timestamp, 'unixepoch') AS date,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'movement end'   THEN timestamp END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'movement start' THEN timestamp END)
       ) AS all_movement,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'load end'   THEN timestamp END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'load start' THEN timestamp END)
       ) AS all_load,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'movement end' AND
                      (SELECT event
                       FROM Table1 b
                       WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MIN(timestamp)
                                          FROM Table1 c
                                          WHERE c.timestamp >= a.timestamp
                                            AND c.id = a.id
                                            AND c.event LIKE 'load %')
                         AND b.id = a.id
                         AND b.event LIKE 'load %'
                      ) = 'load end'
            THEN timestamp END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'movement start' AND
                      (SELECT event
                       FROM Table1 b
                       WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp)
                                          FROM Table1 c
                                          WHERE c.timestamp <= a.timestamp
                                            AND c.id = a.id
                                            AND c.event LIKE 'load %')
                         AND b.id = a.id
                         AND b.event LIKE 'load %'
                      ) = 'load start'
            THEN timestamp END)
       ) AS load_movement
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY id,
         date(timestamp, 'unixepoch')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but i couldn't make it work in the fiddle, even when i replace the `date(timestamp, 'unixepoch')` with `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))`. See fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b43fa/6

Comment: Your solution is quite perfect, it works for different days. But when there entries for another ID on the same timestamps as for another ID (Rows with rowID 41-48), it produces an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1baa/1 . All other things work perfect in this query.

Comment: Updated. Also, `movement` events with the same timestamp could have led to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the query that you are starting with.  I simply don't understand what the third column is.  But, the first two are much more easily calculated using:

```
select (sum(case when event = 'movement end' then timestamp end) -
        sum(case when event = 'movement start' then timestamp end)
       ),
       (sum(case when event = 'load end' then timestamp end) -
        sum(case when event = 'load start' then timestamp end)
       )
from table1
```

From this, it should be trivial to add the group by:

```
select id, date(timestamp),
        (sum(case when event = 'movement end' then timestamp end) -
        sum(case when event = 'movement start' then timestamp end)
       ),
       (sum(case when event = 'load end' then timestamp end) -
        sum(case when event = 'load start' then timestamp end)
       )
from table1
group by id, date(timestamp)
```

Comment: the third row shows the amount of time, where movement tooks place and load tooks place...quite difficult to explain

Comment: @MichaelMeier . . . You accepted a very poor answer on the first question.  It is leading you down painful paths of figuring out what you want.

Comment: Here's an example: In rows 1 to 4, there's no information about load in the range of 135150800 and 1351508020. The load information starts at 1351508080 in row 13. So "20 no load" and "10 no load" shouldn't be used for th calculation of "movement time (load)". Is it allowed that i reopen the other question?

Comment: Here's a subsequent question to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406149/mysql-overlaps-of-two-tables-in-timestamps , thanks.